# int(int(-2)/unsigned(2)) = 2147483647 no warning

Tags: c++, g++

I have a code similar to this:

```
template<typename Ta, typename Tb> Ta doStuff(Ta a, Tb b)
{
    ...
    return a/b;
}
```

As the title says such code would return wrong values with Ta=int Tb=unsigned.

Is there a way to get a warning by g++ for this case ?

Comment: Alternative to warnings, perhaps you could also use something like [`make_signed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee361635.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Use `-Wsign-conversion` option:

```
[nawaz@./]$ g++ filename.cpp -Wsign-conversion
```

Comment: It's -Wsign-conversion, but yeah thats what I searched thanks

Answer (score -2):

Try with:
    g++ *-Wall* code.cpp -o output

Comment: Wall: _This enables all the warnings about constructions that some users consider questionable, and that are easy to avoid (or modify to prevent the warning), even in conjunction with macros. This also enables some language-specific warnings described in C++ Dialect Options and Objective-C and Objective-C++ Dialect Options._ GCC docs.

Comment: I use -Wall .. it doesn't warn

Comment: @KoKuToru: `-Wall` doesn't include any sort of conversion warning, as far as I know.

Comment: In facts `-Wall` doesn't include `-Wsign-conversion` (and apparently neither does `-Wextra`).